# How to detect the empty parking spots?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition, object-recognition

I have some images of the empty parking as shown below.

[image: Empty parking lot]

I 'd like to use deep learning to extract the parking spots. But in the beginning,am confused whether there are several ways to do the following;

1. Treat each parking spot as an object and use object detection to find
   the parking space.
2. Treat the parking spot as a few key points, instead of finding the
   spot, try to find the coordinates of key points on the parking line.

Any ideas on how would I work on these two methods

Answer (score 2):

Object detection is a regression of the bounding box (rectangle) around the object. In this way, the two ways you suggest are equivalent.

What I suggest you to look at is [lane detection](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/lane-detection-with-deep-learning-part-1-9e096f3320b7) for self-driving cars - a well studied problem. It seems that this is a very relevant task (if not the same), so its solution should work for you as well.